# Betareg summary causes memory allocation error

Tags: r, memory, out-of-memory, glm, betareg

I am currently building a model on a data set of 1,000,000 observations using the betareg package in r. My code is:

`m1 <- betareg(rr ~ cred_report, data = mydata, link = "logit")`

betareg seems to run just fine, however, when I go to summarize the model using the summary() function I am thrown the following error:

`summary(m1)`

`Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7450.6 Gb`

I have been able to run the same regression using the glm package and never encountered this error. Also, 7450.6 GB seems like an insane amount of memory required.

Hoping to get some assistance.

Comment: It partially does, there must just be something with the betareg package that demands this incredible amount of memory. I'm wondering if there are workarounds? I'm trying to get a pseudo r squared and p values for my coefficients. Its frustrating that I can't seem to get the nice breakdown from the summary() function.

Comment: The link you sent actually has a sufficient work around. Thanks!